# Binomial Condtional on Number on Successes.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let $X~Bin(10,0.5)$ where $X$ is the number of heads observed in $10$ trials. Given that $X\ge9$ that is I know I will observe 9 heads or more in 10 tosses. I get $P(X=9|X\ge9) = 10/11$, While $P(X=10|X\ge9) = 1/11$. Using Bayes Rule. I know this is correct but I cant understand this intuitively. Here is what is bothering me

1) I am doing $10$ iid trials, $10$ coin flips

2) I know that I got at least $9$ heads.

3) Given this information, why cant I just conduct one additional trial and determine if I will get $10$ heads or $9$, that is $X=10$ or $X=9$.

$P(Head)=0.5$ and $P(Tail)=0.5$ So,

$$P(X=9|X\ge9) = 0.5$$
$$P(X=9|X\ge9) = 0.5$$

Comment: Hm.. Think of a sequence of coin flips: HHHT....H. Now restrict to those with at least 9 heads because someone told you that $X \ge 9$. Among those, how such many sequences have 10 heads? How many have exactly 9 heads? Did someone say that the "first" 9 are the heads?

Comment: It is a very good custom to simplify (as @graham did in his excellent answer) problems if your intuition is protesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I am doing 10 iid trials, 10 coin flips
>
> 2) I know that I got at least 9 heads.
>
> 3) Given this information, why cant I just conduct one additional trial and determine if I will get 10 heads or 9, that is X=10 or X=9.

Because what you describe is the probabilities under the condition that: *the **first** nine trials were all heads*.

However, what you want is the probabilities under the condition that: *at least nine of the ten trials are all heads*.

They are quite different conditions.

---

Let's simplify the example to 3 trials and the condition that at least 2 are heads.  The list of (equally likely) possible outcomes is:

$$\rm \overbrace{\underbrace{HHH, HHT,}_{\text{first 2 are heads}} HTH, THH}^{\text{at least 2 are heads}}$$